# Is there a single word for "of varying heights"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to find a single word for the phrase "of varying heights", as in "vegetation of varying heights". All I can think of is "multiheighted" (which evidently isn't a word), or "heterogeneous" (which doesn't refer specifically to height). Any ideas?

Comment: Since you've tagged this as a single word request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: There are various terms like *assorted* and *variegated* which can mean of different sizes, or varying in other ways, but I'm not aware of any that only refer to height.

Comment: @Stuart F A good use of a response-in-a-comment: something that might help OP, but is far from specific enough to constitute a serious answer on a site aimed at linguists.

Comment: I left an answer specific to "vegetation" below. However, "uneven" growth might suffice (though it is not plant specific)

Comment: Please add a sample sentence with a space for the required word; only one of the two answers posted so far is a direct (and hence relevant) answer. Workarounds need discounting clearly.

Comment: @StuartF ‘variegated’ has a specific meaning with regard to plants of having patches of multiple colours within individual leaves. It’s use with any other intended meaning would be prone to being misunderstood.

Comment: Well, there are the words _macrodiversity_ and _biodiversity_, so why not _acrodiversity_, from Latin _acro-_, forming terms relating to height. (a more familiar word is _acrophobia_, fear of heights). Of course, this is just brain gymnastics, I don't suggest using it at all. "Varying heights" is the usual phrase as you mentioned already unless you have a very specific context with an example. The phrase doesn't really need a single word.

Comment: Do rain forest canopies get more variegated than *triple-canopy* rain forests?

Comment: No, just plants of varying heights.

Answer (score 1):

The most basic word I can think of is "multileveled", but this may or may not work well depending on the context is and what your needs are.

Are you trying to be more concise to make a shorter sentence? Are you trying to find something more poetic, aureate or even Sesquipedalian? Or are you looking for more of a technical, jargonistic word?

Answer (score -2):

I think you could effectively use "**understories**" (or singular - **understory**) to suggest "*vegetation of varying height*".

> The sparse vegetation thickened gradually into multiple
> ***understories*** beneath the canopy overhead.

[TFD - understory/understories](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/understory)

Comment: That only works if they is a canopy overhead, and ‘multiple understories’ is ambiguous, it could be taken to mean multiple discrete areas of under storey vegetation which might share a height.

Comment: Perhaps the word "multiple" is unnecessary or redundant. The word "understories" can be used literally, suggestively, or figuratively - all to the desired effect of the author. On second thought, I think I should have suggested "stratified" - which is a much better answer to the question.